# In Python script for Paraview, can I specify the resolution when I do a SaveScreenshot()?

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

When working ParaView's gui, I can click File > Save Screenshot to create a .png file of my work. With this procedure, I can specify whatever resolution that I want. I want to automate the generation of screenshots in a python script, but I don't see a way of specifying a resolution. Is this possible? I've tried

```
myRenderView.ViewSize = [1000, 1000]
```

which has some sort of effect, but not the desired one.

Looking at [the source code](http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/_modules/paraview/simple.html#SaveScreenshot) for `SaveScreenshot()` I see that a `servermanager.ParaViewPipelineController()` object is created and then its `WriteImage()` method is called. I was thinking that maybe this `WriteImage()` method has resolution arguments that are not a part of the wrapper's arguments, but I can't find the definition of that method. I haven't tried downloading/compiling the actual ParaView source code. I'm just searching around online.

Maybe I should be using vtk directly instead of trying to work through ParaView?

Comment: have you tried the magnification argument? 
http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.html?highlight=save#paraview.simple.SaveScreenshot

Comment: No, I haven't. I want to change the resolution in a way that will change the aspect ratio of the image produced. For example, instead of producing the 2470 x 1714 plots that are being created by my code now, I'd like to make one that is 2000 x 2000 pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subtract [16, 38] from your desired resolution then set the ViewSize parameter. To get an image that is 1000 x 1000 pixels, use:

```
myRenderView.ViewSize = [984, 962]
SaveScreenshot('image.png', magnification=1, quality=100, view=myRenderView)
```

To get an image that is 2000 x 2000 pixels, use:

```
myRenderView.ViewSize = [1984, 1962]
SaveScreenshot('image.png', magnification=1, quality=100, view=myRenderView)
```

Alternatively, you could change the magnification like this

```
myRenderView.ViewSize = [984, 962]
SaveScreenshot('image.png', magnification=2, quality=100, view=myRenderView)
```

to get a 2000 x 2000 pixel image. This choice will change the size of the orientation axes.

Answer (score 4):

I think the ViewSize parameter needs to be able to fit within the resolution of your monitor.

Try this in your script:

```
renderView1.ViewSize = [400, 400]
SaveScreenshot('image.png', magnification=5, quality=100, view=renderView1)
```

This should yield your desired image size.

Comment: I just played with it and found that ViewSize doesn't need to be smaller than the monitor resolution. However, I saw an interesting pattern while I was playing. I set ViewSize to [400, 400] and got images of [416, 438]. Then, when I set ViewSize to [2000, 2000] I got images of [2016, 2038].